# c9.io causes database migration issues when cloning the repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, c9.io

Do I have to "rake db:migrate" all the time when I committed fully migrated repository in github?

For example, I committed the rails repository in c9.io to github.

It was fully "rake db:migrate"d and didn't need to migrate.

But when I cloned my github repository and executed it,

there was a problem that " hasn't been migrated and you need to rake db:migrate"

I want to know what "really rake db:migrate" meaning in rails

and why cloned repo does need "rake db:migrate" all the time

Comment: You're didn't understood the concept of "database migration" and git. I suggest you to find and read something basic about databases and versions control.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to this area.. would you mind recommendate for some website or blog that can understand databases and version control?

Answer (score -1):

rake:db migrate runs all the migrations that should be run and changes your db/schema.rb file. When you clone your repository, you add different migration files, so *Rails* demand you to execute the command again.